# method to map entity to a poco getting invoke error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am getting the "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities." error with this bit of code.

Function Call

```
IEnumerable<OrderListItem> orders;
orders = _service.GetAllForUser<OrderListItem>(userName, mapOrderToListItem);
var foo = orders.ToArray();
```

Functions

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllForUser<T>(string userName, Func<Order, T> mapper)
{
    string displayName = _adService.GetDisplayName(userName);

    return _repo.Query().Where(x => x.OrderedBy == userName)
       .OrderBy(x => x.OrderDate)
       .Select(x => mapper(x))
       .AsEnumerable();
}

private OrderListItem mapOrderToListItem(Order order)
{
    OrderListItem result = new OrderListItem
    {
        DeliveryLoc = order.OrderGroup.DeliveryLocation.Name,
        Department = order.OrderGroup.Department.Name,
        Id = order.Id,
        OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
        OrderedBy = order.OrderedBy,
        Status = !order.ApprovedDate.HasValue ? "SUBMITTED" : !order.ReceivedDate.HasValue ? order.ApprovalStatus == ApprovalStatus.Approved ? "APPROVED" : "DENIED" : !order.FilledDate.HasValue ? "RECEIVED" : "FILLED"
    };

    return result;
}
```

however i **do not** receive the invoke error with this bit of code

Function Call

```
IEnumerable<ProductListItem> products;
products = _service.SearchAll<ProductListItem>(sSearch, 0, all, orderBy, sortDir, productListItemMapper);
var foo = products.ToArray();
```

Function

```
public IEnumerable<T> SearchAll<T>(string sSearch, int skip, int take, Func<Product, IComparable> sortCol, DAL.SortDir sortDir, Func<Product, T> mapper)
{
    switch (sortDir)
    {
        case DAL.SortDir.asc:
            return _repo.Query().Where(r => (r.Name.Contains(sSearch) || r.CatalogNumber.Contains(sSearch)))
                .OrderBy(sortCol).Skip(skip).Take(take).Select(x => mapper(x)).AsEnumerable();
        case DAL.SortDir.dsc:
            return _repo.Query().Where(r => (r.Name.Contains(sSearch) || r.CatalogNumber.Contains(sSearch)))
                .OrderByDescending(sortCol).Skip(skip).Take(take).Select(x => mapper(x)).AsEnumerable();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("sortDir");
    }
}

private ProductListItem productListItemMapper(Product product)
{
    ProductListItem output = new ProductListItem
    {
        Id = product.Id,
        Location = product.WarehouseLocation.Name,
        Name = product.Name,
        Active = product.Active,
        Number = product.CatalogNumber,
        Units = product.UnitOfMeasure.Name,
        UnitsId = product.UnitOfMeasureId,
        LocationId = product.WarehouseLocationId
    };

    return output;
}
```

i feel like i'm just blind and missing something simple.  Why does it work for products but not for orders?

Comment: Use `Expression<Func<Order, T>>` etc.

Comment: why Expression<Func<Order, T>> ?

Comment: EF can only convert expressions into SQL, not functions.

Comment: ok. so by definition i should be using an expression<funct<order,t>>. however, for whatever reason, linq is converting a function to sql for products.  is this just a fluke?

Comment: is this not technically a variation of Expression<Funct<Order,T>>, (x => mapper(x)).

Answer (score 1):

Just for the error message I can think it's because you're trying to use the invoke on the sql server side, try to convert the result first to a collection (list/array) then use your function, so instead "select(e => mapper(e))" do first a ToList() then a select. This is because and IQueryable executes your commands on sql and sql doesn't know about your mapper function.

Edit: keep in mind ToList will retrieve all the records from the db.

Comment: I'm having trouble formatting, but heres the example using your code:
`code`
 _repo.Query().Where(r => (r.Name.Contains(sSearch) || 
r.CatalogNumber.Contains(sSearch)))           .OrderBy(sortCol).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList().Select(x => mapper(x);

Comment: this defeats the purpose of doing a select as before mapping to a collection.  i did this before, and there is a very noticeable performance hit that i don't want.

Comment: With the skip and take methods you only retrieve what you need.

Comment: also, sql was able to figure it out when mapping products. why is sql getting upset when i map an order in the exact same fashion?

Comment: I'm not on a pc right now but maybe you can try replacing the status value with a dummy one and check if the hasvalue call is the problem. Also try first making the select inside the function and then move it out to its own method